# Origin of the quote "Sadness is caused by intelligence"?

Tags: etymology, quotes, phrase-origin, quotations

In social media [(1)](https://twitter.com/liberadordemex/status/1093978039959064577)[(2)](https://www.facebook.com/Moodlivingph/posts/according-to-charles-bukowski-the-sadness-is-caused-by-intelligence-the-more-you/125566699097784/)[(3)](https://www.facebook.com/beastpublcations01/posts/according-to-charles-bukowski-sadness-is-caused-by-intelligence-the-more-you-und/118688403139027/), I have found:

> "Sadness is caused by intelligence, the more you understand certain things, the more you wish you didn't understand them." 
>   —  Charles Bukowski.

But yet I have no reliable source that can confirm me.
I will be grateful if you please tell me about the reak quote-author and origin of this quote with proper resources.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This site is focused on the grammar and usage of the language itself, but it does appear that our sister site [Literature.SE] accepts requests for quote identification, and may be a more suitable place to ask this question.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Literature.

Comment: The Bible (King James Version (KJV)), Old Testament, the book of "Ecclesiastes or, the Preacher" ascribed to King Solomon, [chapter 1, verse 18](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Ecclesiastes-1-18/): "For in much wisdom is much grief: and he that increaseth knowledge increaseth sorrow."

Comment: @choster, Edwin Quotation provenance is long-standingly on-topic on ELU.

Comment: If people want to debate whether this should go elsewhere, please use Meta: topicality of quotations doesn't appear to have been discussed before (although there is at least one [related question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10467). Currently it doesn't appear to be explicitly off-topic. [A question might be on-topic on more than one SE site, as well.]

Comment: Link to the question on Literature SE: https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14583/10231